# Replace function converts text format to number format. Is it excel bug?

Tags: excel, vba, text, replace, numbers

I'm not newbie in excel or googling, but this behavior is surprising/illogical:

1. format column "A" to Text
2. write some numbers into cells, e.g. 74 to A1, A2 and A3 - they are formatted as text, they do not sum up, it looks fine as expected
3. go to find - replace 74 by 75
4. after replace 75's sum up, they are behaving like numbers, even when cells are still formatted as text! I can't get it why?!

This "bug" (?) is causing me some troubles in VBA, because following code does not convert data to expected results ('numbers' in text format) and I simply can't get it to text format:

```
Selection.Replace What:="74", Replacement:="75"
```

Same result when I try any of these methods:

```
Selection.Replace What:="74", Replacement:=Format("75", "@")

Selection.Replace What:="74", Replacement:=CStr("75")

Selection.Replace What:="74", Replacement:="75"
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
```

Only solution that works is this:

```
Selection.Replace What:="74", Replacement:="'75"
```

But I don't want that apostroph in the cell ...

Is there any other way how to replace text, that look like number in the cell - by another text, that look like number?
I feel just dummy to spend an hour thinking about such basics!

EDIT: 
Even this method with usage of named range gives me 75's as numbers (cell format is text):

```
Selection.Replace What:="74", Replacement:=Range("number_75_in_text_format").Text
```

Comment: can you explain this sentence a little better ? *`A2 and A3 - they are formatted as text, they do not sum up, it looks fine as expected`* ? What do you mean by *`sum up`*?

Comment: If is cell content formatted as text, you cannot perform mathematical operation with it. Excel status bar does not show "sum" of cells A1 to A3. This is what I need. However, after replace function, cells content behave like numbers, even if cell is formatted as the text. This is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to describe how you are getting this.   Try running either of these:

```
Sub BugDemo()
With ActiveCell
    .Clear
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = "101"
    .Replace What:="0", Replacement:="7"
End With
End Sub

Sub BugDemo2()
With ActiveCell
    .Clear
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = "101"
    .Replace What:="101", Replacement:="7"
End With
End Sub
```

After replacement, the values remain **Text**

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but this only confirms my finding - BugDemo results in cell formatted as text, but its value 171 is number. BugDemo2 results in active cell formatted as text, but again - its value 7 is number. When I say "is number" means that you can perform math operation with it. And such 171 does not equal to 171 that have been typed to other cell formatted as text.

Comment: **Not at all.**   start with an empty worksheet....format **A1** as Text....enter 1 in **A1** ......in **A2** enter the formula   =A1+1 ..........the formula works to produce **2**

Comment: It is weird, @Gary's Student - what about this: start with an empty worksheet....format A1 as Text....enter 1 in A1 ......in A2 enter the formula =Sum(A1)+1 ..........the formula works to produce 1 ... this is what I need in cell A1.

Comment: however, once I replace "1" in cell A1 (alt-e-e) by "1", formula in A2 .. Sum(A1)+1 produce 2 suddenly ... this is what I do not want, in very simplistic case example

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem.
A workaround that worked for me is to insert ' in front of my text, then replace.
12.3-03 -> Replace 12 -> '12 => '12.3-03
Then replace 12 -> 11 => => '11.3-03

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).